# When is recv() method returning 0?

Tags: timeout, blocking, recv

Could someone explain when is recv() method returning 0? Of course buffer longer than 0 bytes is provided. Method is blocking, so it should wait until it recieves something or throw an error and return -1. I have flag - 0 set. It is not indicating non-blocking mode.

Comment: What `recv()` method? What library are you talking about? What platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN recv Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ... If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is
>   zero.

[recv(2) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv):

> ... The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an
>   orderly shutdown.